# SQL Developer failing to open table in old db version

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle9i

We've connected to an old 9i database with SQL Developer 18.2, and every table we attempt to open the description of returns the following, instead of displaying data/indexes/constraints etc.

[image: error when opening table]

A manual `DESC table_name` works, and there are no exotic column types.

Is there a switch we need to make to make SQL Dev backwards compatible? Can we use an older version of SQL developer as a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

No way, as far as I can tell. SQL Developer works on *supported* database versions which is now ... what, 11g and above? I'm afraid that you'll have to use lower tool version for lower database version(s).

As there's no really an "installation", you can *unzip* 4.x SQL Developer (which works with 9i, but also works with (again - as far as I can tell) at least 12c) into some directory, put its icon onto the desktop and use it whenever you have to work with 9i.

Use your current SQL Developer for more recent database versions, if you have to use some of its capabilities that don't exist in 4.x.

Comment: 11gR2..11204 basically. You'd have to go WAY back to find any version that would work with 9i

Comment: We tried a copy of 4.1 we had on hand to no avail. And if I try download 4.0, it takes me here https://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html

Comment: I have SQL Developers 3.1 / 4.0 / 4.1 (on my hard disk), but - I don't have any 9i database available. Hm. I thought 4.1 would be OK.